# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED EC2 Instance Launch From Image

Tags: centos, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Had this EC2 instance when I got notified that it will be retired.
As usual got an image and tried to launch it and assigned it to be in the same security group as the original ec2.

However, when it gets launched, none of the sites that are on it is accessible.
I simply get an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error.
I was just wondering what could possibly go wrong if I am launching from an image that is taken from an instance that is working. I am 200% confident that it has the same security group as the original ec2 instance.
The original is on a c3.large, the backup instance is also a c3.large.

Any ideas, tips on this please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a plesk server with sites if it helps. Could it have something to do with the change of ip addresses?

Answer (score 0):

Since it shows connection refused, it is unlikely to be a problem with security groups. The default behaviour, had it been an issue with security groups would've been to silently drop the packets. In this case, I'd assume that the service serving the site has not been properly started or it is binding on the wrong interface. Try doing a netstat and see what you get out of it.

To establish if the ip packets are reaching the instance, just do a tcpdump and see if it shows any traffic on the port.